# UILabel is not displaying its correct value even if it is giving the newly assigned value in console

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel which is displayed as a question. Its successfully displaying the question text which has been assigned to it programmatically. But later according to one if else condition, I have to change text in the label.Specifically  I want to display an asterik(*) mark at the end of the string if that is a mandatory question.The * should be in red color and rest of the text should be in black.But it displays only the question not the * mark.If I try to print the questLabel.text it is giving the question with * mark at the end.Here is the code that I am trying

```
  questText = questLabel.text;
         questText = [questText stringByAppendingString:@"✶"];
 NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:questText];
         NSMutableAttributedString *text =
            [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
             initWithAttributedString: str];
             int length = (int)text.length;
            [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor redColor]
                         range:NSMakeRange(length-1, 1)];
            [questLabel setAttributedText: text];
```

If I try to print the value of questLabel.attributedText :

```
Question{
}✶{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
}
```

And the value for questLabel.text is :Question✶

Please help me out with this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: you've initialised your NSMutableAttributedString with str here,
where this str came from?

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic: That is a mistake happened while copying the code.I have edited the code ,Please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should change your code to this.**

```
NSString *questText = questLabel.text;
questText = [questText stringByAppendingString:@"✶"];

NSMutableAttributedString *text =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:questText];

int length = (int)text.length;

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, length-1)];
[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(length-1, 1)];
[questLabel setAttributedText: text];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I tried this solution.But it didn't help me.Still I am getting the values in console.But label is not getting updated

Comment: @iOSManiac, I tried my self and its working, may be there is a problm with your label

Comment: You said it right.Thank you :) .My label frame was wrong..Corrected it.Now it is coming correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.questLabel.text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];

NSMutableAttributedString *starString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"✶" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];

[string appendAttributedString:starString];

[self.questLabel setAttributedText:string];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ Mohsin Shah